# mouse_over on 2 layers 2 objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, layer, mouseout

js. jQuery.
there are two big objects with 0px interval between. they class is '.big'. There are two small objects which class is '.small'. Each small object position have collision with one '.big' object. If mouse_enter '.big' class object then funcStart();  if mouse_leave then funcStop(). 
If mouse from '.big' object goes to '.small' starts funcStop() because mouse is left from '.big', despite the fact that '.small' object is over '.big'.
I need that mouseover on '.small' is active(button), but funcStop() don't need to be run, because mouse is over '.big' object too when it is over '.small' object.

```
<div class=".big"></div>
<div class=".small"></div>
<div class=".big"></div>
<div class=".small"></div>

$(".big").mouseover(function(){
    funcStart();
});
$(".big").mouseout(function(){
    funcStop();
});
```

tried things like:

```
$(".big").mouseout(function(){
    $(".small").mouseout(function(){
        var DONTSTOP = true;
    });
    if(!DONTSTOP) {
        funcStop();
    }
});
```

this is working if i use setTimeout(); , but this time, when we go with mouse from 1st '.big' object to 2nd '.big' object function funcStop(); don't run. tried a lot from stackoverflow. please help. sorry for english.
Thanks.

Comment: you really need to step back and learn some fundamentals.  In the second set of code you're creating a new listener every single time the mouse leaves a `.big` element.  Then every time the mouse leaves a `.small` element you're running a function that sets a new variable then immediately throws it away.  DONTSTOP is undefined to the outer function.

Comment: it was only example. var dontstop was made in start of script. then on leave sets value and then after timeout checked.i tried a lot of all this day was killed by this problem:) i only print abstract things from all methods that i was tried. example was ugly abstracly tooked from dinamicaly generated code. :) but yes, fundamentals, i need to repeat. another thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is sibling vs child.  Check out this sketch showing the difference in behavior.  If the nested div is not a child then the mouse does leave the outer element.  It must be a child for the mouse to stay.   The downside is that if the element extends out then your mouseout is extended as well.

```
<div class ="big">1 big sibling.</div>
<div class ="small">2 small sibling.</div>

<div class ="big">3 big parent.
   <div class = "small">4 small child.</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaJEOo

Comment: oh, thanks. already tried child div before and didn't see that it works :)) or only now started this to work. :) it works now :) thanks.

Comment: also @pwroff is correct mouseover is the wrong event

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [mouseenter/mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) events instead. The reason is the mouseover and mouseout are firing several times while moving cursor around the document which may cause unwanted behaviour.

So try this:

```
<div class=".big"></div>
<div class=".small"></div>
<div class=".big"></div>
<div class=".small"></div>

$(".big").mouseenter(function(){
    funcStart();
    $(".small").on('mouseenter', function(){//Do Your Magic, Mouse is over the .small});
    $(".small").on('mouseleave', function(){//Do Your Magic, Mouse retuned to .big});
});
$(".big").mouseleave(function(){
    funcStop();
});
```

Comment: yes, tried before with all these methods: mouseover, mouseenter, hover........... but problem was in childs(however i tried this all before it didn't worked) or i didn't checked almoast good, when tried mouseenter+child.div)

Comment: True, in your case funcStop() will fire before mouse will enter .small div

Comment: without child .div mouseleave too don't gives a result :) thanks, guys :)

Comment: why did you mark this as the answer if the problem was with child/sibling?